# Create database by C# code in a directory which sql server create its databases

Tags: c#, sql

I want to create a sql database by C# code in a directory in server which sql server create its databases in it.

how can i do that?

Comment: So it sql server installed on the server? Can you connect to it?

Comment: yes, the sql server is installed on the server and i can connect to it and also i can create my database in a folder in networkplaces directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet for what you are asking.

[How To Create A SQL Server Database Programmatically with ADO.NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307283)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using SQL Server 2008 you can use the [Sql Server Management objects (SMO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx)